Error deploying firebase python cloud function
I'm trying to deploy a firebase cloud function, but I'm getting an error and I don't know why. It shows the following error Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK. Did you forget to run '. "/home/marrajuan/Documents/GitHub/cf-test/functions/venv/bin/activate" && python3.12 -m pip install -r requirements.txt'?
I don't know why this is happening, I'm already at my environment and installed all the needed dependencies.

I ran into a similar issue with this as well.  In my Python virtual environment that I have setup, I have only Python 3.11.  The error message that I got was exactly like yours.
Try running
firebase deploy --only functions --debug

And see what the underlying error is.  For me, it was the actual command python3.12 was trying to be called but I don't have that executable since I only have 3.11.  I went ahead and made a symbolic link from python3.12 to python3.11 and ran the deploy call again.  It worked and successfully deployed.
